# Getting Image from url having id

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, image-processing

How can i serve image to client by providing url like

```
http://mydomain.com/image/123?width=100&height=100
```

in above url i dont want to provide image name like

```
http://mydomain.com/image/manoj.jpg
```

how can it is possible in C# .net

Comment: Why `image-processing` tag by the way?

Comment: URL rewriting is what you can do, have a look at httpmodule handler

Comment: may c# code contain imageprocessing like providing height width parameter through url

Comment: But you haven't asked anything about image processing in your question...? You don't need to tag your question with everything that your application does.

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx, You can create `ashx` handler or you need to use URL rewriting

Comment: see this link..http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2538/URL-Rewriting-with-ASP-NET .

Answer (score 0):

I've recently been learning ASP.NET MVC by creating a website from the Northwind DB. Some of the data stored in the Northwind DB are images of the categories. Ideally, I would extract them into files and reference the files but I wanted to see if I could get them from the DB and into a browser. So I had this code laying about.

To get the URL you are looking for, you'll need to use map a new route, I need it before my Default route to avoid conflicts.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Images",
            url: "Image/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Image", action = "GetImageById", id = -1 }
        );
```

Then in my ImageController class I retrieved the image from the Northwind DB (as byte[]) and saved it the output stream as a JPEG

```
    public void GetImageById(int id)
    {
        if (id == -1)
            return;

        byte[] imageArray = db.Categories.Find(id).Picture;

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Northwind Category images were designed for MS Access, which expects a 78 byte OLE header
            int offset = 78;
            stream.Write(imageArray, offset, imageArray.Length - offset);

            Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
            image.Save(HttpContext.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
```

NOTE: Image comes from `System.Drawing`

For ASP.NET you need to use URL Routing (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx). You can use this to map to .ashx handler and return the image with the code above. (Pretty much same answers as Satpal and Vinay but with code example)